# iOS 9 ReplayKit kills AVAudioPlayer randomly

Tags: avaudioplayer, ios9, xcode7

I just add the new `ReplayKit` into my iOS game and tried to start a record with `startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled`. However, the background music of the game, via `AVAudioPlayer`, would be killed 1 or 2 seconds later. I checked all the interfaces within `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` but none of these are triggered:

```
audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying
audioPlayerBeginInterruption
audioPlayerEndInterruption
```

Does anybody have ideas about this?

Answer (score 1):

Have no idea about reason yet but found a walk around.

I cant tell the very reason but it seems the working `AVAudioPlayer` instance will become into an invalid state without trigger any interfaces of the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`. So simple invoking `pause`/`resume` on the instance is useless.

What I have tried is kill that working `AVAudioPlayer` instance and create a new one to play the same music again in the both of the callbacks of `startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled` and `stopRecordingWithHandler`.

The music might be paused for a few milliseconds but it is better than silence.

Comment: @Viper the code is really simple: set the old `AVAudioPlayer` instance to `nil` and then `[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init]` a new instance. Maybe you need the save the `currentTime` of the `AVAudioPlayer` and set it back to the new instance.